# [python]number prime partition with 2

Tags: python

i want to make function(use 'def') prime_partition(n,k)
n is number, k is number of the tuple

my code is...

```
def partition(n,k):
    result=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if isprime(i) and isprime(n-i) == True:
            result.append([i, n-i])
        while len(result) >= k:
            break
        print(result)
```

but i have two problem.

1. partition(100,6) do not make 6 partition but makes all partition.
2. In partition(100,6), there exists two same partition [3, 97],[97,3]. i want to exclude one '[97,3]'

Comment: The rational is not very clear, would you rephrase and give examples (input/output) of what you want to achieve?

Comment: for example...partition(30,3)=[[7, 23], [11, 19], [13, 17]] input is (30,3) output is [[7, 23], [11, 19], [13, 17]]

Comment: If I understand you, given n and k, you want to split n in two summands, i.e., i, n-i, where both numbers are prime. And to keep searching pairs until you have at most k such partitions? Also, if you have (i, n-i), you don't want (n-i, i) as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if` not `while`. Also better `return` the result rather than printing it. You can always print after if needed.

```
def partition(n,k):
    result=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if isprime(i) and isprime(n-i):
            result.append([i, n-i])
        if len(result) >= k:
            return result
```

example:

```
>>> partition(30,3)
[[7, 23], [11, 19], [13, 17]]
```

example to print:

```
print(partition(30, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is an error in the line `while len(result)>k`.
And to avoid duplicates you can iterate only `to n//2`

```
def isprime(n):
    if n==1:
        return False
    if n==2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

def partition(n,k):
    result=[]
    for i in range(1,n//2):
        if isprime(i) and isprime(n-i):
            result.append([i, n-i])
        if len(result) >= k:
            break
    print(result)
partition(30,3)
```